# Magento 2.3.5: Add product to cart with custom options and price

Tags: php, magento, module, cart

Why is the documentation of Magento this bad? It's pretty difficult to build a plugin for it. Anyways I try to add a product with custom price and options. In WooCommerce it's extremely easy to do that.

My code looks like this:

```
protected $_cart;
protected $_productFactory;
```

Constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
}
```

Execute:

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($product_id);     

$params = array(
    'qty' => 1,
    'price' => 100,
    'product' => $product_id,
    'options' => array(
        "test" => array(
            'label' => 'Print Style',
            'value' => 'Test'
        )
    )
);

$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->_cart->save();
```

The controller is called via an ajax post request. The product will be added to the cart and the amount of products equals the quantity I stated in my array.

There are several problems though:

1. The product is only visible in the cart after adding a different product to it via the regular add to cart button.
2. The price is not adjusted. The normal price is used.
3. The custom option isn't visible. The custom option should be visible in the cart, at the checkout and in the order details.

How am I able to accomplish that? I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is product type? Configurable? Let me know the product type and I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OOTB Magento API endpoint for adding product to cart.

Here is the explanation for payload data for different product types, and it can be helpful. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html

But Magento does not allow you to add product to cart with custom price via payload data. 
You will have to add observer and implement the logic around pricing.
More details here.
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-product-to-cart-with-custom-price-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. How am I able to add custom options using the API? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you have an example here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html

Comment: I am not sure if that is what I am looking for. The article describes how to add options to a configurable product. But I am using a single product (It's possible to add options to single products in admin like a text area, but how to integrate a custom option to my payload for API?). If you refer to the configurable product the article shows how to assign fixed values for the configuration but I need to add completely custom values.